# game played in same session python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following game data for PS5 (I am working on python 3.10),

[image]

session_number: sr_no for a session,
venue_number: The location where it is played, 
game: Game played.
start_Ts: session start time
end_Ts=session end time

I want to get an output where for each game I can see what other games were played in the same session and how many times. As an example:
with `Ratchet & Clank`, `Deathloop` is played two times in the same session, `Demon’s Souls`, `Godfall`, `Miles Morales` & `Returnal` are played once in the same session. so basically outcome should look like this

[image]

I put the numbers only for one game here.
The following code will give the data frame in python same as in the picture.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd


# initialize list of lists
data = [[1,'v1','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 13:05:06','29/08/2022 13:54:52',38],[1,'v1','Demon’s Souls ','29/08/2022 13:05:06','29/08/2022 13:54:52',87],
        [2,'v1','Deathloop','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',89],\
        [2,'v1','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',48],\
        [2,'v1','Miles Morales','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',5],\
        [3,'v1','Returnal','29/08/2022 14:11:00','29/08/2022 15:19:10',22],\
        [4,'v2','Deathloop','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',58],\
        [4,'v2','Returnal','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',97],\
        [4,'v2','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',75],\
        [5,'v2','Demon’s Souls ','29/08/2022 20:35:10','29/08/2022 20:36:10',15],\
        [6,'v2','Dirt 5 ','29/08/2022 20:40:34','29/08/2022 20:42:04',94],\
        [7,'v2','Final Fantasy VII ','29/08/2022 20:45:07','29/08/2022 20:51:04',69],\
        [8,'v2','Dirt 5 ','29/08/2022 20:48:45','29/08/2022 20:49:55',85],\
        [9,'v3','Devil May Cry 5','29/08/2022 13:12:33','29/08/2022 13:58:57',90],\
        [10,'v3','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 14:44:07','29/08/2022 14:51:26',78],\
        [10,'v3','Godfall','29/08/2022 14:44:07','29/08/2022 14:51:26',36],\
        [11,'v3','Deathloop','29/08/2022 14:48:31','29/08/2022 14:49:58',43]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['session_number',  'VENUE_NUMBER', 'GAME', 'START_TS', 'END_TS',   'TIME_SEPENT'])
  
# print dataframe.
df
```

Please help...

Comment: you can use `df.gropby('session_number')` to group games and later you can work with every group separately. And you can count games in every group.

Comment: it may need `itertools.combinations()` to create all pairs in every group, and `collections.Counter()` to counts all pairs in all groups. And later you may try to create table with results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are better methods.

You can use `df.groupby('session_number')` to work with every sessions separately.

You can use `itertools.combinations()` to create all pairs of games in every session.

You can use `collections.Counter()` to count all pairs.

And later you can create `DataFrames` with games as column's names and games as indexes and you can use `for`-loop to put values from `collections.Counter()` in correct places.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import collections

data = [
    [1,'v1','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 13:05:06','29/08/2022 13:54:52',38],
    [1,'v1','Demon’s Souls ','29/08/2022 13:05:06','29/08/2022 13:54:52',87],
    [2,'v1','Deathloop','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',89],
    [2,'v1','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',48],
    [2,'v1','Miles Morales','29/08/2022 13:54:17','29/08/2022 14:06:18',5],
    [3,'v1','Returnal','29/08/2022 14:11:00','29/08/2022 15:19:10',22],
    [4,'v2','Deathloop','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',58],
    [4,'v2','Returnal','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',97],
    [4,'v2','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 20:27:32','29/08/2022 20:31:30',75],
    [5,'v2','Demon’s Souls ','29/08/2022 20:35:10','29/08/2022 20:36:10',15],
    [6,'v2','Dirt 5 ','29/08/2022 20:40:34','29/08/2022 20:42:04',94],
    [7,'v2','Final Fantasy VII ','29/08/2022 20:45:07','29/08/2022 20:51:04',69],
    [8,'v2','Dirt 5 ','29/08/2022 20:48:45','29/08/2022 20:49:55',85],
    [9,'v3','Devil May Cry 5','29/08/2022 13:12:33','29/08/2022 13:58:57',90],
    [10,'v3','Ratchet & Clank','29/08/2022 14:44:07','29/08/2022 14:51:26',78],
    [10,'v3','Godfall','29/08/2022 14:44:07','29/08/2022 14:51:26',36],
    [11,'v3','Deathloop','29/08/2022 14:48:31','29/08/2022 14:49:58',43]
]
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['session_number',  'VENUE_NUMBER', 'GAME', 'START_TS', 'END_TS',   'TIME_SEPENT'])

count = collections.Counter()

for key, val in df.groupby('session_number'):
    games = sorted(val['GAME'].to_list())
    pairs = list(itertools.combinations(games, 2))
    print(key, pairs)
    count.update(pairs)
    
#print(count)

for key, val in count.items():
    print(key, val)
    
# ------------

# use games as columns
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=sorted(df['GAME'].unique()))

# use games as indexes
new_df = new_df.reindex(sorted(df['GAME'].unique())).fillna('')

# fill table
for (game1, game2), val in count.items():
    new_df.loc[game1, game2] = val
    new_df.loc[game2, game1] = val    

print(new_df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
1 [('Demon’s Souls ', 'Ratchet & Clank')]
2 [('Deathloop', 'Miles Morales'), ('Deathloop', 'Ratchet & Clank'), ('Miles Morales', 'Ratchet & Clank')]
3 []
4 [('Deathloop', 'Ratchet & Clank'), ('Deathloop', 'Returnal'), ('Ratchet & Clank', 'Returnal')]
5 []
6 []
7 []
8 []
9 []
10 [('Godfall', 'Ratchet & Clank')]
11 []


('Demon’s Souls ', 'Ratchet & Clank') 1
('Deathloop', 'Miles Morales') 1
('Deathloop', 'Ratchet & Clank') 2
('Miles Morales', 'Ratchet & Clank') 1
('Deathloop', 'Returnal') 1
('Ratchet & Clank', 'Returnal') 1
('Godfall', 'Ratchet & Clank') 1


                   Deathloop Demon’s Souls  Devil May Cry 5 Dirt 5  Final Fantasy VII  Godfall Miles Morales Ratchet & Clank Returnal
Deathloop                                                                                                  1               2        1
Demon’s Souls                                                                                                              1         
Devil May Cry 5                                                                                                                      
Dirt 5                                                                                                                               
Final Fantasy VII                                                                                                                    
Godfall                                                                                                                    1         
Miles Morales              1                                                                                               1         
Ratchet & Clank            2              1                                                  1             1                        1
Returnal                   1                                                                                               1
```